# Xcode 8 Audio Stop AVAudio

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

Im trying to stop an SKAction where I play a sound every time I press a button (that is randomly generated in a different location on a background), but I would like to be able do do it by calling an action. I've tried to figure this out for about 2 hours now with absolutely no success. My code where I'm trying to stop the action is below:

```
let clickSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Click.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    //sound action
    let playCorrectSoundEffect0 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Correct0.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    //where im tying to create an action to stop the sound file above from playing
    let stopCorrectSoundEffect0 =
    let playCorrectSoundEffect1 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Correct1.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let playCorrectSoundEffect2 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Correct2.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let endSoundEffect = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("GameOverSound", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Thanks and if you could explain how you did this it would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this by making an if statement for if the score was over a certain point it would stop all actions and then play the wanted sound. It looks like this:

```
if scoreNumber >= 10 {
            removeAllActions()
            self.run(playCorrectSoundEffect1)
        }
```

For any questions just ask me!

Answer (score 0):

My advice don't change for the actual Swift 3, is to choose `AVAudioPlayer` to make your sounds in your game:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound.wav", ofType:nil)!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {
    let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    clickSound = sound
    sound.play()
} catch {
    // couldn't load file 
}
```

and if you want to stop the sound, you should use its `stop()` method. But if you try to stop a sound that doesn't exist your app will crash, so it's best to check that it exists first like this

```
if clickSound != nil {
    clickSound.stop()
    clickSound = nil
}
```

Comment: There is also SKAudioNode but recently many people have some problems like a bad whistling sound, I don't know if iOS 10 resolve this issue. This one is an example of this SKAudioNode problem :https://www.kingsware.de/2016/07/16/using-avfoundation-to-play-audio-in-an-skaction-in-spritekit/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I figured it out after about 3 hours of work last night XD it was an if statement and one simple line of code. But, I've moved on to a new issue. Im trying to make a timer that is triggered when the app is closed so that I can send a notification to "Come Back". If you could help me out with that, it would be amazing.

Comment: Open a new question as SO rules explain,  so you can write all your necessary code and people could focus on your new issue, I will glad to help you.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano,  I never heard any whistling sound, do you know if there is a question about that somewhere?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've read for three times this whistling sound issue about SKAudioNode here in Stack Overflow but I don't remember now where and what are the questions, maybe linked to a particular sound extensions or codec

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano ok, I can't find any on here so if you come across it let me know.  I saw 1 guy on some site mention it, so I asked him to provide a sample.